# Content Security Policy flags script as blocked due to use of 'eval' but script still loads?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

Chrome (111), FireFox (111), and MS Edge (111) all behave the same way. My (abbreviated for clarity) CSP header includes:

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self';script-src 'self' blob: *.usercentrics.eu;connect-src 'self' *.usercentrics.eu;font-src 'self' data: ;img-src 'self' blob: data: *.usercentrics.eu;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ;frame-src 'self' ;object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';script-src-attr 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests
```

When loading the page, the "Issues" tab in DevTools reports "Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript" for the 3rd-party script https://app.usercentrics.eu/browser-ui/latest/bundle.js.

[image: DevTools script-src blocked]

However, when I look at the Network tab, I see that this script loaded and apparently ran just fine?!

[image: DevTools bundle.js load Status 200]

If I examine the script, it does have an unsafe *new Function()* string expression.

This makes me wonder:

1. How did this script with what's [identified as an unsafe eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_eval_expressions) still load given that script-src 'unsafe-eval' is NOT allowed?
2. Is there a "hole" in how CSP headers are evaluated that would allow it to be bypassed and "eval()" functions maliciously inserted and run?

Comment: How would the browser determine _that_ any script resource contained eval, if it did _not_ load that resource first? _"However, when I look at the Network tab, I see that this script loaded and apparently ran just fine?!"_ - why would looking at the _network_ tab tell you anything about whether the script actually _executed_?

Comment: "*the script does have an unsafe `new Function()` string expression.*" - well then **that part** did not run fine, it threw an exception. But of course the script ran, otherwise it couldn't have reached the point where it was trying to eval a string.

Comment: @Bergi, you appear to be correct. The script loads and runs but throws an exception when encountering the unsafe new Function() expression. Though the browser would have the ability to reject/block the entire script if it found an internal expression that failed the CSP, it's helpful to know that other parts of the script will still run. I worded my original question poorly. It's understood the script would need to be read (loaded) by the browser. The question is really about whether it runs at all or not if it contains an unsafe eval, which has now been answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. The browser can't know that a script contains elements violating the eval policy until it has been loaded. It needs to load and verify it.
2. Your options are to add 'unsafe-eval' to script-src (not recommended), rewrite the offending functions eval/new Function/setInterval/setTimeout as described in https://web.dev/csp/#eval_too, or to stop using/replace the offending script.

Comment: "*a script contains elements violating the eval policy*" - that is actually not what is verified. This would require static analysis, which is hard for JavaScript, and is not done. The script is loaded and simply *executed* (which is allowed by the CSP), but calling `new Function` anywhere does throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi pointed out, the browser still loads and runs scripts (assuming the script-src header allows the src) even if it contains an unsafe eval. However, the script will throw an exception when encountering any unsafe eval expressions when running, unless also specifying 'unsafe-eval' in the script-src directive, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.